# How to initialize a variable and calling "apply { }" at the end

Tags: kotlinpoet

I'm trying to auto-generate classes were we create variables like this with KotlinPoet:

```
class test {
   var testObj: CustomObject = CustomObject().apply { custom = "custom" }
}
```

So far I've tried looking at the PropertySpec in KotlinPoet, but can't find any functions to generate variables while calling `apply()` at the end.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PropertySpec.Builder` has an [`initializer()`](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/kotlinpoet/com.squareup.kotlinpoet/-property-spec/-builder/initializer/) method that you should use in this scenario, however, there are no specialized API for generating initializers that include an `apply` block. See the [`CodeBlock` documentation](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/kotlinpoet/com.squareup.kotlinpoet/-code-block/) for more info on how to generate code for your initializer, plus there are many examples of generating similar constructs in [KotlinPoet's unit tests](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet/tree/master/kotlinpoet/src/test/java/com/squareup/kotlinpoet) that you can use for inspiration.

Comment: Can you please write the code that would generate the code in question? I have a similar issue but with a multiline `apply` block. Unit tests are poor why of documenting features (hard to search, hard to see results).

Answer (score 1):

[CodeBlock](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/kotlinpoet/com.squareup.kotlinpoet/-code-block/) has a [beginControlFlow](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/kotlinpoet/kotlinpoet/com.squareup.kotlinpoet/-fun-spec/-builder/begin-control-flow.html) method where you can define `apply` method using the following code. `beginControlFlow` method will deal with indentation and curly brackets.

```
beginControlFlow("${variableName}.apply")
//... do sth here
endControlFlow
```